# python-eve oplog in not working in my application

Tags: python, eve

As per the instructions mentioned in the document, in my application, I have made required configuration for OPLOG but for some reason, it is not working as expected.

I made a few HTTP requests to my application nothing is logging. My code is:

```
 RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET','POST','DELETE']

 ITEM_METHODS = ['GET','PATCH','DELETE']

 X_DOMAINS = '*'
 X_HEADERS = ['Authorization','If-Match','Access-Control-Expose-Headers','Content-Type','Pragma','Cache-Control']
 X_EXPOSE_HEADERS = ['Origin', 'X-Requested-With', 'Content-Type', 'Accept']

 OPLOG = True
 OPLOG_ENDPOINT = 'oplogger'

 DOMAIN = {
   'user': {
     'additional_lookup': {
       'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
       'field': 'username',
     },
     'schema': {
       'firstname': {
         'type': 'string'
       },
       'lastname': {
         'type': 'string'
       },
       'username': {
         'type': 'string',
         'unique': True
       }
     }
  },
  'oplog': {
    'url': 'oplogger',
    'datasource': {'source': 'oplog'}
  }
}
```

Any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be hitting a [known issue](https://github.com/pyeve/eve/issues/1074) with the latest release of Eve. It's fixed in v0.8-dev ([changelog](http://python-eve.org/changelog.html#version-0-8)), which is scheduled for release next month (give or take).

If you verify this is indeed your problem and are in a hurry, you can install the development version right away with:

```
 pip install git+git://github.com/pyeve/eve.git
```

See the [installation instructions](http://python-eve.org/install.html#installation) for detailed instructions.